# Why is my Intent not being matched?

Tags: android, android-intent

I've tried following the article about Intents and Intent Filters in the hope of moving my app from explicit to implicit intents (seems to make things a little simpler). However, my `Intents` are never matched, no matter how hard I try. Pertinent info below:

```
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Provider.constantsUri);
    //in.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT); is this required?
    startActivity(in);
```

and in my Manifest:

```
<activity android:name="Equation"  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
                <data android:scheme="content" android:host="com.espian.formulae.pro" android:path="const"></data>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

and the definition of constantsUri:

```
public static Uri constantsUri = Uri.parse("content://com.espian.formulae.pro/const");
```

I've also tried forming the `Uri` with a `Uri.Builder`, but no luck there either. Is there something really obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an intent defined like this in one of my apps:

```
    <activity android:name=".TwitterAuthActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="moodfling" android:host="twitterauth" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And if I put this in a new test app:

```
    Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("moodfling://twitterauth"));
    startActivity(in);
```

It launches to the activity. Sounds like something is wrong in your filter definition, but I'm not sure what offhand. Try copying out my version and make sure it works for you, then try to narrow it down as you change parts.

Comment: It seems that if I only have a scheme and host in the data (like your example) it works, but if I put a path in (which is required) it doesn't match? Thing is, the exception says nothing matched the _exact same Uri_ as the what the Uri parses. Going to try using data types instead

Comment: Are you sure you have the path correct? I think if you Log constantsUri.getPath() from your example it'll actually show "/const". Try changing your intent filter to include the leading slash.

Comment: The stuff outlined in your comment worked (i.e. it requires the leading slash) thanks :)